# IOS Simulator : JavaScriptCoreWTF::CrashOnOverflow::crash:

Tags: ios, safari, react-native, ios-simulator, react-native-ios

While testing in iPhone SE simulator pressing CMD+R freezes the app with this error in xCode:
[image]

React Native version: 0.34,
platform: iOS.

Started after upgrading of xCode to version 8.0

Comment: Can you provide any code or a sample application which reproduces the issue?

Comment: @JAL I created a fresh new React Native app by running `react-native init TestApp` , and then ran it with `react-native run-ios` , and it runs just fine , but when i press *Cmd+R* it crashes

Comment: You are pressing CMD+R from Xcode, as in an attempt to run the app in the iPhone SE simulator? Could you show the breakpoints tab of Xcode, are there any there that you aren't expecting?

Comment: @BHendricks , no , i'm making changes in Javascript code, then pressing CMD+R in Simulator to re-run the app in it. I'm not sure about breakpoints tab, because i am not iOs but React Native developer. This is what i see in console in xCode: https://jsfiddle.net/dzL2831z/

Answer (score 1):

I saw this [thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/306) where some people were reporting issues with live reloading. Although their issues were not the same as yours perhaps the root of the problem is the same. Their solution was found in [another thread](https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/90) and it was related to Watchman. In particular, their problem was solved by changing the permissions of the following file:

```
chmod 644 ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist
```

Comment: Thanks, but still no go, i tried everything, changed the permissions, reinstalled the watchman, even upgraded NodeJs , nothing helps. I think the problem is in Safari , because it happens only when Safari is open for the app' debugging